# Steps to setup xlt maven project into eclipse

Tags: compiler-errors

Getting build path errors

Downloaded XLT project from the xceptance and imported the xlt project into eclipse.Followed below steps: 1.File>Import>General>Existing projects>Selected the testposters from samples and finish.